Chromecast Device Not Detected on MacBook Hotspot
I am attempting to connect my Chromecast to a VPN network using my MacBook Pro as a hotspot, but I am encountering an issue where the Chromecast is not detected on my Mac. Here’s the setup I have followed:

My MacBook Pro is connected to the internet via Ethernet.
I have configured Network Sharing to share my VPN connection over Wi-Fi (Share your connection from: VPN & To devices using: Wi-Fi).
The Chromecast is connected to this Wi-Fi hotspot.
When I search for Chromecast devices in Chrome, none are displayed.
Interestingly, when I connect my mobile phone to the same hotspot network, I can cast from my mobile to the Chromecast without any issues.

The problem lies in the fact that the Chromecast does not appear on my MacBook.
Questions:

Are there specific settings or permissions on macOS that I need to adjust for Chrome to detect the Chromecast?

Is there a known issue with Chromecast not being recognized over a MacBook hotspot?


Any guidance on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!
